# Using Tensorflow object detection API to detect objects and classify objects by color

Tags: tensorflow

I am able to use Tensorflow to train the model on my own dataset. For example, I have trained a model to only detect the safety helmet and the result is good.

[image: Result]

My plan for next step is to classify the identified safety helmet by colors. But I still in search of methods.

I am wondering should I retrain the model with different label map like: `[item1 red_helmet] [item2 blue_helmet]` and label my training dataset respectively? Or is there any other tricky way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: It's good that I found it here! Could you please share your materials? I just started working on the same topic (safety helmet detection). I looked for a dataset with no success. Maybe you have a git-hub repo on that?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the region of interest in the picture.

All you need is extract the helmets from the picture and pass the cropped images to openCV routine that can detect colours.

Thats it, you are done :)